# Ionic ion-range does not so updated values

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, ionic-framework, dom

I am using ion-range element with Vue.

```
<ion-range v-model="profile.travelMate.age" min="18" max="120" dual-knobs="true" pin="true" step="1" ticks="false" color="secondary" />
```

On the code, this.profile.travelMate.age.lower and this.profile.travelMate.age.upper have always the right values so v-model works. But when I set the initial values on beforeMount lifecycle hook, ion-range does not show the set values but it shows the initial values.

```
beforeMount() {
// getting data from the database
this.profile.travelMate.age.lower = preferences.get("minAge");
this.profile.travelMate.age.upper = preferences.get("maxAge");
// Variables have the right values after the update but ion-range DOM element still shows the old values.
}
```

How could I force ion-range element to update itself? Or any other solution?

Comment: It seems that beforeMount hook will be finished before .then method of a Promise has been run. The values will be set too late and that is why the ion-range shows the initial value. How could I delay exiting from beforeMount hook before all Promises have been solved and their code has been executed.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, it seems to me that v-model on ion-range does not work well. Occasionally, the UI element updates when the value changes, but quite often, no update.

I found a workaround. I added key attribute to ion-range. By changing its value, an update is triggered. So I use key attribute only to force an update when needed.